# Embedding Quantum SL(2) into the Quantum Matrices

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra

Let $M_q[2]$ be the algebra of quantum matrices over the complex
numbers with the usual generators $a,b,c,d$ and the relations $ab
= qba$, ... etc. Moreover, let $SL_q(2)$ be the quotient of
$M_q(2)$ by the ideal generated by det$_q-1$, where det$_q = ad -
qbc$. Given a basis of $SL_q(2)$ it is easy to construct an
embedding of $SL_q(2)$ into $M_q(2)$. What I would like to know
is: Can anyone see a canonical way of embedding $SL_q(2)$ into
$M_q(2)$?

Comment: The paper below doesn't quite answer your question, and yet...

http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/2027.42/30793/1/0000447.pdf

Comment: Would you mind explaining what $q$ is?  Also, could you give the relations besides $ab = qba$?

Comment: It's OK I found Takeuchi's MSRI notes . . . 

Comment: The relations are very well known. See, for example, Majid's "What is a Quantum Group" linked on the Wikipedia Quantum Group page.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are looking for here. Could you be more explicit about canonical? Sorry if I'm being slow. 